# Refinitiv Data websocket stream stop with DEBUG output : "Normal Closure"

Tags: python, session, websocket, handler

When using Refinitiv.data 1.0.0.20b with websockets in RD_DEBUG True,
after few hours application spits to console the flowing debug messages.
I wish to handle this occasion on a "top level" application that imported
Refinitiv.Data and connects websocket feed data.

Desired result: once refinitiv.data websocket close with "Normal Closure" debug message
I wish the top level (importing) application execute some handler (on_update/on_status/on_event/on_error/on_refresh ) or callback.

Existing behavior: Non of the documented refinitiv.data handlers / callback / event handlers is executed/ launched on "top Level" python application.

Can someone share his experience how to bind a callback/handler from refinery.data websocket/session to my application?

```
++Sent raw: b'\x81\x90\xe4*\x1a\xa1\x9f\x08N\xd8\x94O8\x9b\xc4\x08J\xce\x8aM8\xdc'
++Sent decoded: fin=1 opcode=1 data=b'{"Type": "Pong"}'
++Rcv raw: b'\x88\x10\x03\xe8Normal Closure'
++Rcv decoded: fin=1 opcode=8 data=b'\x03\xe8Normal Closure'
++Sent raw: b'\x88\x82\x0fI\xb4\xba\x0c\xa1'
++Sent decoded: fin=1 opcode=8 data=b'\x03\xe8'
```

Thanks
Ori

Comment: I think you mean "Desired result" rather than "Expected result", right?  You know that the code you currently have won't do what you want, and you don't expect it to.   You're asking how to change the code to do what you desire.

Comment: Thanks @CryptoFool  I am not a writer. Fixed accordingly.